# IIS URL rewrite not work for remove trailing slash

Tags: iis, slash, trailing

I need to add "Remove trailing slash" if this slash is 2 or more.

Using this Regex pattern `(.*)/{2,}$` works in test pattern but does not work on live environment.

```
For example:
https://test.com/ => https://test.com/
https://test.com// => https://test.com/
https://test.com////// => https://test.com/
```

Comment: Enable FRT to reveal what exactly happens under the hood, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then you know how to tune the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the parameters you are using, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*?)//+(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Comment: This not work, return ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS because this cache only 1 "/" and redirect to "/" and return too many redirect. i need to cache 2 or more.

Comment: I modified my parameter above, it should be `^(.*?)//+(.*)$`.